# How to convert &#10 from sqlite2 to <br/>?

Tags: php, sqlite

When I insert text with newlines to **sqlite2** db, all the line breaks come out as `&#10;`.

I can strip them out with

```
$content = html_entity_decode($row['Content']);
```

But how can I convert them to `<br/>`?

I've tried so far

```
$content = str_replace("&#10;",'<br/>',$row['Content']);

$content = preg_replace("/\&\#10\;/", "<br/>", $row['Content']);

$content = str_replace("\x0a", "<br/>", $row['Content']);

$content = str_replace('&#10;','<br/>',$row['Content']);

$content = str_replace("&#10;","<br/>",$row['Content']);
```

with no luck. The `&#10;` is still there as it would be without these lines.

What next?

Comment: What does "with no luck" mean? What happens? Are we meant to guess?

Comment: Have you tried `$content=str_replace('&#10;','<br/>',$row['Content']);` (single quotes in first argument) ?

Comment: @arkascha, it sort of given, that 'no luck' means the values are unchanged. But I updated the question to clarify it.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: the `str_replace` command above certainly _does_ work, it _does_ replace the chars you mention when they are in the given string. That is why I asked. Looking at the answer you accepted I'd say: the issue was that those chars actually were _not_ inside that string. Aparently you did not really evaluate what string you really have but only relied on some indirect output method. So one hint: if it comes to deciding what special chars have been converted to which _always_ use a hexeditor, not some terminal or text editor. It would have shown the chars as linebreak...

Comment: @arkascha, for the sake of reality, it should work. However, in this case, it definitely DID NOT. You're absolutely right, I evaluated most likely the characters incorrectly. However, the accepted answer solved the case and hopefully it will help some other char-issue-noobs like myself.

Comment: Sure, all fine: what I meant is: you tried to replace characters that were not present in the string. That certainly cannot work. You asked the wrong question. I did not want to be hypocritic. I only wanted to show up what you might want to do next time.

Comment: I asked the question with the details I had in my hands at the given time. Anyhow, lesson learnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$content = nl2br(html_entity_decode($row['Content']));
```

Comment: You are a SAINT! :) Works perfectly. Thank you.